# How to stop Embedded Tomcat gracefully and tomcat should get stopped only after the current processing requests have to complete

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, server

We have implemented embedded tomcat model java application. and running war file from java -jar command. the problem is how can i stop the server. and before server getting stopped, already fired requests to the server should get processed. then only i have to stop server. how can i implement this. thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that's what `Tomcat.stop()` does. You could implement a simple servlet which waits for a minute and see whether `Tomcat.stop()` waits for it. Don't forget to call `Tomcat.destroy()` to completely shout down tomcat.

Comment: do i need to extend `Tomcat` class?

Comment: No, checkout https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html

Comment: can you suggest any doc for tomcat internal work flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your application when it is finished write to file /somedir/yoursecretfile

If using linux, make a cron job which check periodically if file /somedir/yoursecretfile exist and if the file exists, stops a web server (maybe with ps | grep | xargs or something like that).

If using other OS, use replacement for cron for that OS and script which stops a webserver.

Comment: actually using jmx mbeans i can able to stop server.(service mbean through jconsole). and i may need to extends Tomcat class and have to do customization. is that good idea?